# Building a form which passes input into a livechat

Tags: javascript, wordpress, zendesk

We are trying to get the following to happen:

The customer enters an amount and clicks start chat:
Requests get send to live chat where the following message is sent:
I would like to sell //amount //Product

[image: message]

Currently, we are able to make it send the "amount" input to the chat, however, we are unable to get the following to work:

- Prompt when the amount is to low (You need a minimum of "x")
- Get it to send a message along with the amount: "I would like to sell" + amount + Product name

From a previous question posted and some documentation on the live chat platform we got the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458524/passing-a-form-input-into-a-chat/55461360#55461360).

API documentation:
https://api.zopim.com/files/meshim/widget/controllers/LiveChatAPI-js.html#say

Best reply:

```js
$zopim(function() {
  $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent hte form from redirecting
    let message = $('input[name="important"]').val();
    console.log(message);
    $zopim.livechat.say(message);
  });
});
```

Script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<form name="question"> 
  <input type="text" name="important"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

We took the above-mentioned code and came up with the following
form:

```
$zopim(function() {
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // prevent hte form from redirecting

var important = $('#amount').val();

if($.isNumeric(important)) {
{if( important < 30) { $('.error').html('We only buy 20 or more.').show(); 
    } else 

var message = 'I would like to sell ' + important '.'; 

$('.error').html('').hide(); $zopim.livechat.say(message);

let message = $('input[name="important"]').val();
console.log(message);
$zopim.livechat.say(message);
});
});

<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<form name="question"> 
  <input type="number" placeholder="Amount" name="important"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Start chat"> 
</form>
```

However this doesn't appear to be working. We have very little experience in JavaScript, so if someone knows what we are doing wrong or has a better solution, please let us know.

In conclusion: We want a form that sends the input to a live chat paired with text.

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes with your code -

In line - `var important = $('#amount').val();`, you are grabbing html element whose id is `amount` but your html do not have any input whose id is `amount`. So, your `important` var is undefined. To make it work add id `amount`.

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Amount" name="important" id="amount">
```

`.val()` returns values in `string` format. So your `if($.isNumeric(important))` will always be `false`.

```
var important = parseInt($('#amount').val());
```

The condition below is not properly formatted. As well there is no html element with `.error` class

```
if($.isNumeric(important)) {
        {if( important < 30) { $('.error').html('We only buy 20 or more.').show(); 
            } else`
```

Add to your html

```
<div class="error"></div>
```

Since your `error` element visibility is based on `important` var. So, initial state would be `hidden`. In your `css`, add `.error {display:none}`.

```
const error = $('.error');
let message;

if($.isNumeric(important)) {
    if(important < 30) {
        error.text("We only buy 20 or more.").show();
    } else {
        error.hide();
        message = 'I would like to sell ' + important '.'; 
        $zopim.livechat.say(message);
    }
}
```

P.S - Your `form` tag is placed below the `script`. You are accessing the html elements before it gets properly loaded. Always place your `script` before closing `</body>` tag or place your `jquery code` within `$(document).ready()` or `$(function(){ // Your code })`.

Always use `const` or `let` instead of `var` to declare variable so as to avoid the `variable hoisting` issue.